# Error al mandarle a node texto con las comillas ``

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nodejs, textarea

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con node, y le tengo que mandar texto de un textarea, y resulta que en uno de los casos, en el textarea el texto contiene estas comillas:

```
`mensaje de prueba`
```

y al leer el body con:

```
const body = req.body;
```

me salta el siguiente error:

```
(node:20568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

he probado a mandar el mismo texto sin esas comillas, usando las comillas dobles " o las comillas simples ' y me funciona bién, pero necesito que me funcione con estas comillas ` alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error??? muchas gracias.

mi código actual es el siguiente:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/copiar",
                data: `text=${$(this).val()}&id=${id}`,
                success: function () {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

y en el servidor en node recibo los datos tal que así:

```
 const body = req.body;
```

y al leer el body es cuando me da el error

Comment: Por favor agrega el código en donde manejas esa llamada, no solo el req.body

Comment: ah okey, ahora lo edito